# How to perform relational operations on hibernate template with spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

How to perform relational operations on hibernate template with spring crud operations.

for example I want to insert data employee table but also it inserts to its relational table address and how to get delete, update and fetch operations.
for example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEE")
public class EmployeeBean implements Serializable  {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="employee_id")
    private Long employeeId;

    @Column(name="firstname")
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name="lastname")
    private String lastname;



    @Column(name="cell_phone")
    private String cellphone;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="employee",  cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private EmployeeDetail employeeDetail;

    //getters and setters


}


@Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEEDETAIL")
public class EmployeeDetail implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="employee_id", unique=true, nullable=false)
    @GeneratedValue(generator="gen")
    @GenericGenerator(name="gen", strategy="foreign", parameters=@Parameter(name="property", value="employee"))
    private Long employeeId;

    @Column(name="street")
    private String street;

    @Column(name="city")
    private String city;

    @Column(name="state")
    private String state;

    @Column(name="country")
    private String country;

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private EmployeeBean employee;


 //gettters and setters

}
```

I have tried it google from last 5 hours but there is no clue i get, please do some good example your help is appreacited.

Comment: why the people do the down vote for this , If someone have confusion regarding such types of topic then do help not neglect.

Comment: If someone has confusion regarding such types of topics, then he can't help, because he is confused. The problem with your question is: You googled, but you didn't tell us what's the problem with the tons of tutorials you must have found? For example [this one](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/).

Comment: dont get it wrong, I want example like one table have relation to another, i know how to perform operations on single table

Answer (score 0):

You can see below like this is help you for hibernate relational database mapping.

http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2013/09/hibernate-one-to-one-mapping.html
and
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-one-to-one-mapping-tutorial-using-annotation/

Comment: Thanks , but there is no spring mvc there?